# Nuxt 2.12.2: Filling the store with the new fetch method

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

It is not clear in the current documentation, since the big change on the `fetch` method. As I understand that in the [doc](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch) it says:

> fetch(context) has been deprecated, instead you can use an anonymous middleware in your page: middleware(context)

So `context` is no longer available? What is passed into the **new** `fetch` method then?

And how do you access the `store` in the `context`? For example, prior to 2.12.2, we can use the `fetch` method as follows:

```js
// pages/index.vue
async fetch ({ store }) {
  await store.dispatch('....')
},
```

So, I assume that the code above will not be working soon in Nuxt 3 in the future. Then how do you fill the store data when you are on a page?

Currently, it seems that you still can access the `context` as the **first argument** in the **new** `fetch` method. What about in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is passed into the **new** `fetch` method then?

The `fetch` hook no longer has any arguments.

> how do you access the `store` in the `context`?

To access the context within the `fetch` hook, use `this.$nuxt.context`; and you can access the `store` like this:

```js
const { store } = this.$nuxt.context
store.dispatch(...)

// or
this.$nuxt.context.store.dispatch(...)
```

Comment: This detail should have been included in official documentation.