# NuxtJS: How to access Vuex state on Server side

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs

I am using NuxtJS [fetch()](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/#nuxt-gt-2-12) hook to get asynchronous data from a REST service. Following is the request

```
async fetch() {
  let response = await this.$axios.$get(`http://localhost:8080/app-server/v1/post/id/${this.$route.params.id}`);
}
```

I also need to send an optional query parameter `uid`, which is the user id in case a user is logged in. User Id is stored in Vuex state and can be accessed on client side like below

> this.$store.state.user.userDetails.id

But when the page is reloaded and *fetch()* is executed on server side this returns *null*. I am looking for a way to access this state on server side as well. I tried using Nuxt context `this.$nuxt.context` like below but it too returns *null* when runs on server side.

> this.$nuxt.context.store.state.user.userDetails.id

Any suggestions how can I access Vuex state on server side. Thanks

Comment: your store is getting cleared after a page refresh so there is no data.

Comment: @Ifaruki user information is saved in cookie as well. So it is retrieved from there after page refresh.

Comment: ok and where do you retrevie it/ how?

Answer (score 0):

There is predefined method nuxtServerInit which you can use in your store to get user ID to vuex on server side before fetching data. https://hashinteractive.com/blog/using-nuxtserverinit-in-vuex-to-fetch-component-data/

Then you can retrieve it from the store in the fetch method. [Nuxt 2.12.2: Filling the store with the new fetch method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524721/nuxt-2-12-2-filling-the-store-with-the-new-fetch-method/62542174#62542174)

Comment: But in our case logged-in user's Id is saved into a cookie. So, if Vuex store is cleared out by page reload it is fetched from the cookie and added to store. I guess your solution is about fetching data from a back-end API and populating the store. But in our case the details are on the client side only and we need to make them available on server during server side rendering.

Comment: You can just use information from these links to make it applicable for your solution. `nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }, { res })`, then get cookie from res.body and save it to vuex. Then create getter for user info and call it in your fetch method with `this.$nuxt.context.store.getters`.